# Showing that $\mathbf I-\mathbf L(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)^{-1}\mathbf L'\mathbf I\mathbf L(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)^{-1'}\mathbf L'$ is an idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to show that $\mathbf I-\mathbf L(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)^{-1}\mathbf L'\mathbf I\mathbf L(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)^{-1'}\mathbf L'$ is an idempotent matrix where $\mathbf L$ is a $p\times r$ matrix, $\mathbf I$ is a $p\times p$ identity matrix, and $\mathbf L'\mathbf L$ is assumed to be invertible.

**My try:**

Let $\mathbf m=\mathbf L(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)^{-1}\mathbf L'$ so that

$$\mathbf Q=\mathbf I-\mathbf L(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)^{-1}\mathbf L'\mathbf I\mathbf L(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)^{-1'}\mathbf L'=\mathbf I-\mathbf{mIm}'$$

We have that

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{QQ}
&=(\mathbf I-\mathbf{mm}')(\mathbf I-\mathbf{mm}')\\\\
&=\mathbf I-\mathbf{mm}'-\mathbf{mm}'+\mathbf{m}\mathbf{m}'\mathbf{m}\mathbf{m}'\\\\
&=\mathbf Q-\mathbf{mm}'+\mathbf{m}\mathbf{m}'\mathbf{m}\mathbf{m}'\\\\
&=\mathbf Q-\mathbf{m}'\mathbf{m}+\mathbf{L}\underbrace{(\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L})^{-1}\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L}}_{=\mathbf{I}}(\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L})^{-1'}\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L}\underbrace{(\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L})^{-1}\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L}}_{=\mathbf I}(\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L})^{-1'}\mathbf{L}'\\\\
&=\mathbf Q-\mathbf{m}'\mathbf{m}+\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L})^{-1'}\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L})^{-1'}\mathbf{L}'\\\\
&=\mathbf Q-\mathbf{m}'\mathbf{m}+\mathbf{m}'\mathbf{m}'\\\\
\end{align*}

I'm not sure how I can proceed in showing that $\mathbf Q^2=\mathbf Q$ or where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the relationship between $L$ and $L'$?

Comment: @Jbag1212 $L'$ denotes the transpose of $L$

Comment: Here I'm letting $L'$ denote the transpose of the matrix $L$. Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step should be $(I-mm')(I-mm')$; for some reason you wrote $m'm$ in the second term. If you propagate this correction through the rest of your work, you will get $Q-m'm + m'm = Q$ at the last step.

Comment: Oddly enough, I got the same thing. I will edit my attempt.

Comment: @Remy I guess you should also note that $(A^{-1})' = (A')^{-1}$ when $A$ is symmetric and invertible.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that property.